# Selecting Item of NSMatrix programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmatrix

How can I programmatically select one of the items in an NSMatrix? I believe it is an NSControl so I was looking in that particular documentation, however I could not find any information on the specific topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
-(void)selectCellAtRow:(NSInteger)row column:(NSInteger)column
```

in NSMatrix?