# Programmatically select a cell in NSMatrix automatically makes the cell visible

Tags: objective-c, nsscrollview, nsmatrix

I've been working with some legacy codes, and the current situation is I have a NSMatrix as a group of radio buttons inside a NSScrollView. The NSMatrix is at the top of the NSScrollView, and the NSScrollView can contain up to hundreds of other subviews.

Every time when the function `-(void)selectCellAtRow:(NSInteger)row column:(NSInteger)column` is used to programmatically select a radio button in the NSMatrix, the NSScrollView will automatically scroll up so that the selected radio button will be visible. Some customers find it very annoying.

Is it a default behavior of that function? How do I stop this automatic scrolling?

Related, but not the same, question:
[Selecting Item of NSMatrix programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537973/selecting-item-of-nsmatrix-programatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectCellAtRow:column:` triggers `scrollCellToVisibleAtRow:column:`. Subclass `NSMatrix`, override

```
- (void)scrollCellToVisibleAtRow:(NSInteger)row column:(NSInteger)col;
```

and don't call `super` (if the matrix is invisible).

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you, Willeke!